# how to fix "can't convert String into Integer" after calling the split function in puppet?

Tags: arrays, debian, puppet

how to fix the following code?

```
$parts = split('test-test','-')
notice( $parts[0] )
```

see: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.6.8/function.html#split

for me it results in the following error:

```
can't convert String into Integer at ....:2
```

tried to fix it with:

```
notice( ${parts[0]} )
notice( "${parts[0]}" )
```

with the following command i got now error, but also no output

```
notice( "${parts}" )
```

i have debian squeeze running with its stable puppet package 2.6.2-5+squeeze3 puppetmaster is also debian stable 2.6.2-5+squeeze3

the question is "ripped out" of a "real" problem, i am try to get the duritong shorewall module up and running (https://github.com/duritong/puppet-shorewall)

there the shorewall::entry fails with the message:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
can't convert String into Integer at 
/etc/puppet/modules/shorewall/manifests/entry.pp:9 on node
```

full code

```
define shorewall::entry(
    $ensure = present,
    $line
){
    $parts = split($name,'-')

    concat::fragment{$name:
        ensure => $ensure,
        content => "${line}\n",
        order => $parts[1],
        target => "/etc/shorewall/puppet/${parts[0]}",
    }
}
```

Comment: Squeegy: it's Ruby in a rather indirect way through Puppet config files.

Comment: I honestly can't replicate this: https://gist.github.com/1433433 what version of puppet are you running?

Comment: strange, the same code doesn't work for me :( puppet version is 2.6.2-5+squeeze3 as posted above.

Comment: This has been bounced around, but it should never been migrated off SO in the first place; we'll keep it here for now and try to let it breathe =)

Comment: Call you include the code where you're calling the shortwall::entry definition ?

Comment: @pwan i directly includet it in the node. but is it relevant? if the split function does not work standalone, it can't work in the shorewall code, do it? i will try to use the newest puppet version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into [Puppet issue #5127](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5127), and that the problem is with array dereference instead of the split function.

The fix is to upgrade to at least puppet version 2.6.3.

Comment: this could be the solution, if i run "$parts = split('test-test','-')" without trying to notify i get no error. i will try to upgrade as soon as possible and credit your answer if upgradeing worked. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `split("some-text", "-")` is equivalent to `$_.split("some-text", "-")`. The result depends on the value of `$_`, which contains the last string read by gets. What you probably want to do is `"some-text".split("-")`, which results in `["some", "text"]`.

Comment: thank you, i think you answer is "ruby", i removed the ruby tag, it is a puppet question, where split is a special function. so your answer is wrong for puppet. see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.6.8/function.html#split

Comment: Oh that might be true, I didn't realize that.